# Unable to build iOS Project on Xcode 9?

Tags: ios

I was running ios project on Xcode 8.3.2 and it was working fine.
Now I am running same project on Xcode 9 Seed. And I am getting lots of warning with fix suggestion. When I use Fix option it adds stub methods in the implementation Class and after that it give number of errors.

[image]

And I am trying to build project on Xcode 9 , it stuck at initialising datastore and never complete even after two or three hours later . [image]

Can anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: clean you project and try to build again. Otherwise close Xcode and re-open it again.

Comment: I have done all these thing , even i have deleted the derive data and run it again but still facing the same problem.

Comment: You may or may not be surprised, but I couldn't find any documentation on this. I had to build it in Appcode before it would start building again. Probably because Appcode is made by JetBrains and is therefore a worthwhile thing for a developer to use. I would say there will be an update shortly and they'll fix some of these glitches. Plus plenty more rants from people like me